# Ubuntu 10.4 lts netbookedition

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, terminal, login

I hope somebody here will be able to help me. I have put a checkmark in the user settings not to ask for a password at login and now I'm stuck my netbook does not ask for a password but i'm also unable to do anything else it does not show me the desktop anymore, so I was wondering if I could reverse this through the terminal ? thanks

Comment: What *does* it show, if not the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Try Pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get to a shell.

From there, try logging and running `gdm` to get your desktop back.